# Drive the directory on my computer is in Thai

Tags: hard-drive

When I installed drive on my computer the folder is in Thai. Yes, I live in Thailand but I don't speak or read Thai. The installation process was in Thai. When there was a language choice I selected English. How do I get the folder to be in English?

Comment: What do you mean with "When I installed drive on my computer the folder is Thai"? What is 'drive' and which folder is Thai?

Comment: [s]he is talking about the folder names in "c:\", wants them all in english too.